# Ionic.js or Appgyver Steroids for Angular MPA

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, mobile, ionic-framework

I'm working on a somewhat large Angular.js CRM mobile app that uses [Ionic JS Framework](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/) for the UI elements. I've been debugging using [Ripple Phonegap Emulator](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ripple-emulator-beta/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc?hl=en). I've had literally no performance issues anywhere. The transitions are fast and fluid.

However, once I deployed using Phonegap Build and loaded the APK on an Android device, the performance was terrible. Ionic.js has [known problems](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/phonegap-performance-on-device/7656) with Master/Detail transitions which can be worked around, but even apart from these screens (when I am not loading any external content), the app was very slow.

My question is, should I try to adopt Appgyver's [Steroids Framework](http://www.appgyver.com/steroids) for my UI elements and transitions? Will Steroids offer faster performance and would it be worth the transition?

I'm targeting Android and iOS.

Answer (score 4):

If you were to develop you app iOS first, I would definitely recommend the AppGyver platform. However, currently the Android runtime is going through a complete rework, with the new (currently called "Fresh") Android runtime not yet having any native UI features implemented, which would provide a noticeable boost in your app's performance.

That said, the first native UI features are being implemented in the next few releases, so depending on your deadlines, it could be worth the wait.

Answer (score 4):

In the current state of Steroids, your iOS ionic app will be sped up dramatically. The more processes and complexity you add to any single page app, the slower and more cluttered it gets. DOM gets overpopulated, and things just chug. With Steroids for iOS, MPAs really solve that problem because each page is a separate OS process. All transitions are performed natively. That means they don't just look native, they actually are.

As for Android, the latest version of the Steroids Android client (Fresh Android) runs a Chromium 35 based WebView... that will beat the pants off builds you get get from anywhere else currently. Without the Chromium build, you're building for the platform standard browsers, which for a common phone like Samsung S3, you'r building Chrome 9 - yikes! No amount of javascript magic will help you there. In the coming 4 - 6 weeks, AppGyver is releasing MPA for Android. This will totally change the performance Android Hybrids ;)